# Sencha Touch 2, before filter on the router, to check for user's auth state

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am developing a Sencha Touch 2 app with user authentication.

I use a token for authentication.

The logic.

Check is a token exists in local storage:

```
var tokenStore = Ext.getStore('TokenStore'),
token = tokenStore.getAt(0).get('token');
```

If there is a token, check if it's valid.
I am doing a read from a model which is connected to my API which, returns success or fail - depending on the token - if it's valid or not.

```
 TestApp.model.CheckAuthModel.load(1, {
                scope: this,
                success: function(record) {
                  // Here, I know the token is valid

                },
                failure: function() {
                    console.log('failure');
                },
                callback: function(record) {
                    console.log('callback');
                    console.log();
                }
           });
```

And here is the router, which handles the logic for the views:

```
Ext.define("TestApp.controller.Router", {

    extend: "Ext.app.Controller",

    config: {

        refs: {
            HomeView: 'HomeView',
            LoginView: 'LoginView',
            ProductsView: 'ProductsView',
            ProductsViewTwo: 'ProductsViewTwo'
        },

        routes: {
            '': 'home',
            'home' : 'home',
            'login' : 'login',
            'products' : 'products',
            'testingtwo' : 'testingtwo'
        }
    },

    home: function () {

        console.log('TestApp.controller.Router home function');

        var initialItem = Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(),
            comp = this.getHomeView();

        if (comp === undefined) comp = Ext.create('TestApp.view.HomeView');

        Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(comp, {
            type: 'slide',
            listeners: {
                animationend: function() { 
                   initialItem.destroy();
                }
            }
        });
    },

    login: function () {

        var initialItem = Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(),
            comp = this.getLoginView();

        if (comp === undefined) comp = Ext.create('TestApp.view.LoginView');

        Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(comp, {
            type: 'slide',
            listeners: {
                animationend: function() { 
                   initialItem.destroy();
                }
            }
        });
    },

    products: function () {

        var initialItem = Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(),
            comp = this.getProductsView();

        if (comp === undefined) comp = Ext.create('TestApp.view.ProductsView');

        Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(comp, {
            type: 'slide',
            listeners: {
                animationend: function(){
                    initialItem.destroy();
                }
            }
        });
    },

    testingtwo: function () {

        var initialItem = Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(),
            comp = this.getProductsViewTwo();

        if (comp === undefined) comp = Ext.create('TestApp.view.ProductsViewTwo');

        Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(comp, {
            type: 'slide',
            listeners: {
                animationend: function(){
                    initialItem.destroy();
                }
            }
        });
    },

    launch: function() {

        console.log('TestApp.controller.Router launch!');
    }
});
```

Now, how can I link the router with the check auth model callback?

I want to know the auth state when the app reaches the router.

In other MVC frameworks, I could do a before filter, on the router, check for auth and handle the routes accordingly.

Can i do this in Sencha Touch 2?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think this section in the documentation is exactly what you need:

> **before** : Object
>   Provides a mapping of Controller functions to filter functions that are run before them when dispatched to from a route. These are usually used to run pre-processing functions like authentication before a certain function is executed. They are only called when dispatching from a route. Example usage:

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Products', {
    config: {
        before: {
            editProduct: 'authenticate'
        },

        routes: {
            'product/edit/:id': 'editProduct'
        }
    },

    //this is not directly because our before filter is called first
    editProduct: function() {
        //... performs the product editing logic
    },

    //this is run before editProduct
    authenticate: function(action) {
        MyApp.authenticate({
            success: function() {
                action.resume();
            },
            failure: function() {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Not Logged In', "You can't do that, you're not logged in");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-before

Of course, it's still up to you to decide whether you should check every time or should cache the auth result for sometime.

**Updated to answer comment below**
Honestly, i am not sure how they was going to declare that static method Authenticate in Sencha (you would be able to do it normally through Javascript i think, i.e.: prototype).

But there are other better options to solve just that Authenticate function:

- Just create a singleton class that handle utility stuffs.
  http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-singleton
- If you really want to use MyApp, you can declare within the Ext.app.Application (in app.js). Then call it from the global instance **MyApp.app.some_function()**. I wouldn't exactly recommend this method because you change app.js, that might bring problem if you upgrade sencha touch.

Comment: Nathan, this is perfect, works like a charm. ;) Maybe if you look, you can tell me something - I have notice MyApp.authenticate({}) - is there a way to add functions to MyApp and keep them in separate places, basically add them to MyApp proto? and use them allover the app?

Answer (score 0):

You could implemented auth check in application's launch function or in your auth controller's init function and based on the response redirect the to appropriate url.  Something like this:

```
  TestApp.model.CheckAuthModel.load(1, {
            scope: this,
            success: function(record) {
               this.redirectTo("home/");

            },
            failure: function() {
                this.redirectTo("login/");
                console.log('failure');
            },
            callback: function(record) {
                console.log('callback');
                console.log();
            }
       });
```